# How to pass id parameter using php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, guzzle

I want to pass the id from the controller to route but I'm having trouble with it. I am a newbie at this so I would really appreciate your help!

Controller:

```
public function fetchVideo(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $input = $request->all();

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$input['token'],
        'Content-type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ];

    $params = [
        'id' => $input['id'],
        'fields' => $input['fields']
    ];

    $response = $client->request ('GET', 'https://api.dailymotion.com/video/{id}', [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'query' => $params
    ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/video/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\dailymotionController@fetchVideo');
```

Comment: It usually goes from route to controller, not the other way around. You're requiring the parameter, so you should require it in the function definition. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
public function fetchVideo(Request $request, $id) // <- {id} parameter in the route
{
   ...
   $response = $client->request('GET', "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/{$id}", [...])
   ...
}
```